# Google Places API, is saving results allowed?

Tags: google-places-api

I would like to build a site that lists hotels, stores etc in cities. I can query the Places API, but I feel it is illegal to use it in such a manner. Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 1):

It's [free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) for non-commercial use.

> Google Maps (formerly Google Local) is a web mapping service application and technology provided by Google, free (for non-commercial use)

However, Google recently added a [limit](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits) to [it](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Limits).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Terms of Service for the Google Maps API (or Google Places API): http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

You can also check out the FAQ page, of which I think this section would be the most relevant to you: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_mysite

Good luck.